# Difference between declaring 2d vectors by two ways

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

What is difference between these two ways of declaring 2d vectors:

`vector<vector<int>> b(n+n-1);`

and

`vector<vector<int>> b(n+n-1, vector<int>(n+n-1));`

Comment: Do you know the difference for 1D vector? `std::vector<std::string> v1(42)` versus `std::vector<std::string> v2(42, "hello")`.

Comment: The first creates a `vector` containing `n+n-1` empty `vector<int>`s (empty in the sense of having no elements, or each element reports `.size()` is zero).   The second creates a vector containing `n+n-1` vectors of `int` that each contain `n+n-1` elements, all initialised to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int>> b(n+n-1);
```

Allocate a vector `b` with `n+n-1` elements and initialize the elements **with default value (a vector with zero elements)**.

```
vector<vector<int>> b(n+n-1, vector<int>(n+n-1));
```

Allocate a vector `b` with `n+n-1` elements and initialize the elements **with the specified value (a vector with `n+n-1` elemements)**.

Comment: let say n=2. then how would be `b` looking?

Comment: @sahdg what's your guess? MikeCAT gave you all the information you need to answer that question.